# Angular 5 lazy loaded module doesn't work on refresh

Tags: angular, .htaccess, wamp, angular5

> **Note about this issue**: I noticed it only happens using certain types of build process. Since I'm using `angular-cli` this error will appear everytime I compile the application using `ng build`. The only exception is when I use `ng build --prod`. I use any other flag I used to use, such as `--dev --aot` then I'll get the error where I can't refresh the page.
>
> When using ng build --prod the refresh on the page will keep the application running as expected. But during development it means I need to run the command everytime a change is made on the code, otherwise I'll get errors like:
>
> `(void 0) is not a function`

I'm trying to use Angular 5 lazy loaded modules using wamp server but I'm having problems when I refresh the page using lazy loaded modules. This is my routing configuration:

```
// Root routing config
export const mainRouting: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: '',
        component: PortalComponent,
        canLoad: [ResolveGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            {
                path: 'page',
                loadChildren: './modules/page/page.module#PageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'user',
                component: UserComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
                    { path: 'config', component: ConfigComponent },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
];

// LazyLoaded routing config
export const pageRouting: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            { path: 'about', component: PageAboutComponent },
            { path: 'condition', component: PageConditionComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

Everything is working as expected. I can navigate to the home page of the application, I can access the lazy loaded routes (`page/about` and `page/condition`), the `PageModule` is loading only on demand, etc..

The problem is when I'm on the url `/page/about` (for example) and I refresh the page, then I get a 404 error.

If I'm on the url `/user/profile` and refresh the page, the application load as expected, because the `user` is not lazyloaded, it's within the main module.

I'm already using this .htaccess configuration

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But only in this specific case it's not working. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the .htaccess is working ? I believe the redirection within apache servers requires a plugin to be active.

Comment: @AlexBeugnet It's working, because if I remove the `.htaccess` the `/user` url. Actually, any other url that is not the root will not work, even the `/home` url stop working when I remove the `.htaccess`.